# jQuery tabs won't mark current selected index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs for a project with the AJAX approach. When you select and option from the listed tabs the content gets changed but the current tab stays the same.

Here's my js code:

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
                    if (url) {
                        location.href = url;
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <%= Html.TabLink("Inicio", "Dashboard","List") %></li>
                <li>
                    <%= Html.TabLink("Mis Listas", "Index", "List")%></li>
                <li>
                    <%= Html.TabLink("Mis Amigos", "FriendDetail", "List")%></li>
                <li>
                    <%= Html.TabLink("Invitar", "Invite","List") %></li>
            </ul>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Should you be returning false?

Comment: I guess so. If I don't I wouldn't be able to change the current content displayed. Removing the return false makes the whole thing to not work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning false is halting the remainder of the code necessary to switch to the tab you've selected. If you're attempting to stop the user from redirecting and simply showing a new URL, use window.location.replace()

e.g.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
     select: function (event, ui) {
          var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
          if (url) 
               window.location.replace("asdadf");
     }
});
```

Comment: With this the problem persists. Even though the url gets changed the current tab is still the first one.

Comment: Would you mind updating your description and showing the surrounding HTML and Jquery then? This may be a problem outside of your .tabs() constructor.

Comment: Hi, I just added the HTML I'm using as you requested.

Comment: The HTML you have should make the tabs, but the list elements (<li>) within the unordered list (<ul>) should contain links that correspond to hidden divs within your HTML.

Comment: For example, if your first element was <li><a href="#hidden-div-1">open the first div</a></li> then there should be HTML later on within your code such as <div id="hidden-div-1"></div> - is that in there at all?

Comment: That would be cool if the content gets render upon the request of the page. If you read carefully I'm loading the content using AJAX so instead of using the selectors for the hidden content I'm using the actual url that loads that content.

Comment: You still need the divs, regardless. Even if they're empty. You could set up an .ajax() call to retrieve the information and place it within the divs if need be. Otherwise you'll need to do something along the lines of this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

Comment: Look at the description of the structure here. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode

Comment: Ah, have you read it? I just copied and pasted the code and it works fine with a few mock pages. You should read the documentation as well.

Comment: Just did and made it work, *Without the divs*. The place holder for the ajax content is a span next to the link.

Comment: If you don't mind just fix your answer so I can mark it as the solution :). Since thanks to your insistence on reading the documentation I noticed I was actually missing something.